# SSH to user with no password

Tags: windows-10, ssh, passwords, openssh

I have a windows user that has no password set. How can I ssh into that account. I have set

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

but it still asks for password. I know I can use a key pair but I would like to know how to ssh into a windows user that has no password without a key pair.

Comment: You have a typo - it should be `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Comment: @JW0914 - The typo shouldn’t matter since the default more than likely isn’t being overridden by setting PasswordAuthentication to “no”

Comment: @SasukeUchiha - A blank password is still a password, if you want literally no password prompt, then your only option is to use key authentication.  A blank password is obviously incredibly insecure and if the system is accessible to the internet will be completely compromised (there are services that literally search for vulnerable servers)

Comment: It is also just immensely easier to use a password. Time to move forward.

Comment: @JW0914 it is correct in the config. My mistake when copy pasting. Also the default value is yes

Comment: @John I am aware but I like to learn. This is a scenario that I found when I was just messing around.

Comment: @Ramhound i know how insecure it is supposed to be. But I just can't connect. So is it really insecure. I mean if you have physical access to the machine, yes an attacker just have to turn on the machine and press sign in. But ssh doesn't seem to let you in.

Comment: @Ramhound I am fine with the password prompt. But pressing enter with password prompt blank doesn't work. So how do you enter a blank password to ssh?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha - I don't know the syntax you are using to connected to the machine.  If the server is using the configuration you have modified, and the Windows username has a blank password, when prompted you should simply enter nothing.  You will be prompted for a password, but the password is "nothing", so you press Enter.  If the machine is accessible to the internet, it would be very insecure, they don't need physical access if you have a username without a password and have OpenSSH Server running

Comment: @Ramhound I used `ssh username@ip` that's all. The server is using the configuration that I modified. But when I press enter, it asks me for the password again and throws a authentication error.

Comment: I was asking for the configuration file itself, you should specify the machine name of the remote machine, that will probably resolve the authentication error. Logs from the server that show the reason for the authentication error is also required to answer your question